# RISC-V: Do 12-bit immediate logical operations operate on the whole register?

Tags: riscv, immediate-operand, sign-extension, riscv32

I am trying to write a simulator for a RISC-V CPU and can not find a definitve answer to my question.

Let's say I want to use

```
ANDI rs1, rd, 0xFFF
```

with rs1 containing 0xFFFFFFFF and the immediate value being 0xFFF.

Does the ANDI operate on the full register and just fill the remaining 20 bit of the immediate with zeros so the result in rd will be 0x000000FFF?

Or are the higher 20 bits ignored and the result in rd will still be 0xFFFFFFFF?

Same question for XORI and ORI commands.

Comment: It's right there in the manual: [ANDI, ORI, XORI are logical operations that perform bitwise AND, OR, and XOR on register *rs1* and the sign-extended 12-bit immediate
and place the result in *rd*](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/blob/a2ae53f289802e8857516404ab8d2591d614aedb/src/rv32.tex#L513).

Comment: I read that, but wasn't aware of what sign extension means, or rather I assumed the wrong meaning, thanks though!

Comment: Sign extension is a pretty fundamental concept you should understand instinctively by the time you're doing something as advanced as writing a CPU simulator. The specification spends quite a bit of time [emphasizing the criticality of sign extension](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/blob/a2ae53f289802e8857516404ab8d2591d614aedb/src/rv32.tex#L421) to justify why immediates are encoded in the strange way they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Immediate value is **sign extended**,
12 bit FFF will translate to 32'hFFFFF_FFF for RV32

so the values being AND-ed will be

rs1_data & 0xFFFFF_FFF